# Which curve (surface) is this?

Tags: plane-curves, curves, least-squares

We're having trouble fitting our data... well, we don't even know which function we should fit onto. Anybody knows if this function is well defined mathematically?

[image: first angle]
[image: second angle]
[image: third angle]
[image: fourth angle]

Comment: 1. Do you expect one variable to be a function of the other two, or are all three connected implicitly? Generally, details about how the data were collected and what they mean is likely to improve the quality of answers. 2. A single perspective projection is qualitatively helpful, but if you expect one variable to be a function of the other two, could you please replace the images with orthogonal projections along the respective coordinate axes, so that the two variables being shown are in standard orientation (positive axes pointing rightward and upward)?

Comment: Yes, one variable is function of other two, ie. z = f(x, y)